# Eclipse plugin: How to open external browser from Intro.xml on the Welcome page

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

How can I display a url on external browser from a link tag on the a custom Eclipse Welcome page plugin?

The following code is an example of what I have so far from the intro.xml, which is working when I click on the link from the Eclipse Welcome-page, but it displays the url from the Eclipse internal browser, and I need to display it on the external browser.

```
                <link 
                    label="Google" 
                    url="https://www.google.com/"
                    id="link-img-google" 
                    style-id="link">
                    <text>Please read the "Please visit Google"</text>
                </link>
```

Comment: That sounds like it's up to the user's General/Web Browser preferences.

Comment: Yeah but I need to force to display the link from external browser when the user clicks on the link, and at the moment it opens the link using the Eclipse internal browser. Any idea how to change that behaviour from the Eclipse Welcome-page plugin? or maybe some other approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by changing the url attribute content structure to open external browser, here is the change:

```
            <link 
                label="Google" 
                url="http://org.eclipse.ui.intro/openBrowser?url=https://www.google.com/"
                id="link-img-google" 
                style-id="link">
                <text>Please read the "Please visit Google"</text>
            </link>
```